# assign model attribute value to instance method parameter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following model

```
class myclass
  def mymethod(a, b, c, d = 'e')
    StoredProcedure::Test.exec!(
        a, b ,c ,d)
  end
end
```

I have attribute f's value available in model but don't know how can i assign it to parameter b. 
I tried doing `def baz(a, b = f, c, d = 'e')` but not working. 
How do i assign f's value to param b in model?

Comment: `class Myclass
  def mymethod(a, b, c, d = 'e')
    b = f
    StoredProcedure::Test.exec!(
        a, b ,c ,d)
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to set b to nil, then assign it in the method if the user hasn't specified a parameter:

```
class myclass
  def mymethod(a, c, b = nil, d = 'e')
    b ||= f
    StoredProcedure::Test.exec!(a, b, c, d)
  end
end
```

Also note that I re-ordered the parameters. Optional parameters must come after required parameters.

Of course, if you want b to be f all the time and don't expect users to override it, you should just get rid of it entirely:

```
class myclass
  def mymethod(a, c, d = 'e')
    StoredProcedure::Test.exec!(a, f, c, d)
  end
end
```